# Is this quote from James Gleick about the Manhattan project accurate?

Tags: atomic-theory

In his book 'Chaos' he says, 'In theory the WWII atomic bomb project was a problem in nuclear physics. In reality the nuclear physics had been mostly solved before the project began, and the business that occupied the scientists assembled at Los Alamos was a problem in fluid dynamics.'

Comment: *Chaos* has extensive references.  Did you look there?

Comment: This is James Gleick's own conclusion. (I share his opinion). What is the question then? References? Any good history of the project.

Comment: The real meat of the project could be argued to be scaling up to industrial levels of isotope separation (U) and plutonium production. But that generally did not greatly involve those at Los Alamos. And, the fluid dynamics issues really didn't impact Little Boy, only Fat Man.